# How do I find the version for a Dynamic Library (.dylib file) in MACOS

Tags: java, macos, dylib

I have a Dynamic library (abc.dylib) with version say 6.0.1.104 in my local file system. I can go ahead and right click the file > Get Info and find it's version. But I want a way by which I can do it programmatically in java or from any terminal command. Is there any way to do this?